# Google Apps user primary Calendar API v3 timezone update not working?

Tags: timezone, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm using Google APIs Explorer to set Google Apps user primary calendar timezone - tried both update ("Services > Calendar API v3 > calendar.calendars.update") and patch ("Services > Calendar API v3 > calendar.calendars.patch") but timezone is not changed.

Timezone is not updated in Calendar application and get ("Services > Calendar API v3 > calendar.calendars.get") returns old value that does not reflect update or patch...

Is it a bug in Calendar API v3 or am I missing something?

Example Calendar API v3 requests and responses:

```
Request:
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/user152%40bracnaagencija.com?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer ya29.1.AADtN_UPBwkU29qf5Tg1rEOZAtBdjv0OArg_RcAaUGNd4K43Pnonf6vK5JcJqfT6ht2bh31n793sry9AIs3-_xk
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer
{
"timeZone": "Europe/Zagreb"
}

Response:
200 OK
- Show headers -
{
"kind": "calendar#calendar",
"etag": "\"XxbwS1MD0Y8jfGZwMQdPS4xI8-w/G_gC5jDwlI70wsfMFOhGzUPev2U\"",
"id": "user152@bracnaagencija.com",
"summary": "Unknown Unknown",
"timeZone": "Europe/Zagreb"
}

Request:
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/user152%40bracnaagencija.com?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Authorization:  Bearer ya29.1.AADtN_UZRmbrmkJvNRyA9739wcpsKPRObitSAnfMeh1WcEan0Z6UML3ryFZaoy0OJELLYu6mgg
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

Response:
200 OK
- Show headers -
{
"kind": "calendar#calendar",
"etag": "\"XxbwS1MD0Y8jfGZwMQdPS4xI8-w/ykVLEmnFygm61gmsUBUa0zgsq0E\"",
"id": "user152@bracnaagencija.com",
"summary": "user152@bracnaagencija.com",
"timeZone": "America/New_York"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Europe/Zagreb` is a valid IANA/Olson identifier, but it's just a link to `Europe/Belgrade`.  It shares the exact same data. (For details, see [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), or [the original source data](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/b8e081b8bae00f6939103b15657591af5856ddce/europe#L2463-L2479).)

It's entirely possible (though I am not 100% certain) that Google Calendar does not support links in its list of time zones.

Try `Europe/Belgrade` and see if that works.

Comment: I've tried with Europe/London and other valid values from Olson database and there is no difference - update and patch are not working. If you try with invalid value you get Error instead of OK so that is not the problem. Anyway - thank you for the comment :-)

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for checking.  It was just a guess.  You might want to submit a bug report to Google if you haven't already.

Comment: I've submitted issue 3521:
https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3521